# Need to get out of the airport during a 4 hour layover in Dubai?

Tags: transit, layovers, dubai, pakistani-citizens

I'm travelling from Lahore to Paris with a 4 hour layover in Dubai through Emirates airlines in June. I wanted to see my dad in Dubai so I wanted to know if i could get out from the airport? I hold a Pakistani passport but I have been born and brought up in Dubai, its just that I've been shifted to Lahore for some reasons temporarily.

I wanted to know if I could get a free visa, or do I need to go through immigration or some other processes beforehand?

Comment: So do you also have UAE citizenship, just no passport from them right now?

Comment: Please don't edit garbage into your post.

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply for a visa in advance as Pakistan is not on the [list of countries](http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) eligible for a visa on arrival.  Four hours will not give you much time, as you'll have to pass through immigration and security.  If your father does not live close to the airport, you might to arrange to meet him at the airport.